# Restrict class constructor visibility in Scala 2.9

Tags: scala

Greetings,

How can I make the Foo constructor visible only to this package (unit test + companion object) ?

I don't want to be able to instantiate Foo outside of this 2 files...

**Foo.scala**

```
package project.foo

class Foo(val value: String)

object Foo {
  def generate: Foo = new Foo("test")
}
```

**FooSpec.scala**

```
package project.foo

import org.spec2.mutable._

class FooSpec extends Specification {
  "Foo" should {
    "be constructed with a string" {
      val foo = new Foo("test")
      foo.value must be "test"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Scala 2.9

Comment: By the way, the value returned from a constructor call is never `null`. If your string constructor is missing, it won't compile. If for some reason (full heap, etc.) the object cannot be created, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Pellet: of course ! I know that, was just for the example :)

Comment: OK, just making sure other people (who might not know it) don't misinterpret your code.

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Pellet> seen, I've edited the question to avoid confusion

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
package project.foo
class Foo private[foo] (value: String)
```

Then the constructor of `Foo` is only accessible from the `foo` package.

You can read more about Scala's visibility (look especially for scoped private and scoped protected) [here](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch05.html#VisibilityRules).